# Speeding up ASP.NET website publishing

Tags: asp.net, build-process, build-automation, publishing

Is there any way in ASP.NET website project, that allow to publish it from command prompt and I can continue working on project, or if it is not easy to use , at least speed up my publish task?

I know about the auto publishing tools like TFS or CruiseControl, so please don't tell me these ways.

I am thinking to create a .bat file , that I'll run everytime I have to publish. but it should not take changes made by me during its running process.

[asp.net single file publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551615/asp-net-single-file-publish)

I really like the Answer given by Ludwo, providing more information on that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MsBuild to publish your websites in parallel. [Start with this article](http://blog.ovesens.net/2009/01/publish-a-website-application-using-msbuild/). It is about publishing one website using MsBuild. Define your projects inside ItemGroup and use MSBuild task this way:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(YourProjectsToBuildInParallel)" BuildInParallel="true" ...
```

The final step is to [enable parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997047/how-to-run-tasks-in-parallel-in-msbuild) for MSBuild task.

Comment: the answer looks great, can you please explain how to add this file to my project, I don't know much about MSBuild.

Comment: Save MSBuild project as PublishWebSite.proj. It can be used as standalone project file or as a part of your other MSBuild scripts. You can execute it using MsBuild.exe: "MSBuild.exe PublishWebSite.proj /t:Publish" [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Open another Visual Studio to continue :P. Publishing mechanism can detect updated and can send only changes. So dont upload full site everytime, if its really disturbs you.

Comment: I am thinking to create a .bat file , that I'll run everytime I have to publish. but it should not take changes made by me during its running process.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551615/asp-net-single-file-publish

Comment: is it really necessary to make changes while its uploading? How much time does it take to upload your site?

Comment: Oh its a big site, it takes 5 minutes to publish, I want to make few changes and upload it so that testers time should be utilized, I don't want to make changes all day, upload at the end and let my Testers play ping-pong :)

Answer (score 0):

**Use source control and a build server mechanism.** The build server should be able to pull from source control when you commit a change, build the project, do any unit tests you may/should have, and then deploy to a test site.

Depending on which build server platform you use you may or may have to do varying amounts of work. In the past I have used Bamboo by Atlassian. Fantastic product but you have to configure the deployment using MSBuild - it's fine but it can take some time to get it perfect. I am sure there are some good examples out there for it.

How it will work for you:

When you are finished working on a file/issue you can commit your changes. The build server will then detect these changes and wait a varying amount of time (waiting for you to commit more) e.g. 3 minutes, check out your changes, and deploy. You can set up notifications when the deployment is done to goto your testing team - with a link in the email saying where the site is, and what the change that occurred (based on your SVN commit log).

So your net effort is to check a file in with a correct comment - and you are finished.